# Rendering Konva.js script to image in python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, konvajs, python-pdfkit

While generating a pdf in python using pdfkit, I am required to attach a diagram drawn using konva.js script to the pdf. I have attached the konva.js script to the html code string but the image is not being rendered into the pdf while generating. The diagram is being drawn by passing the values dynamically to the javascript functions. But while saving the html code seperately, the image is being rendered into the browser, but not in the pdf while converting. Even while trying to save the konva.js to image also, the diagram is not being shown but instead only a while blank screen. Can anyone help me with this issue?!

I tried to install different packages such as selenium, pyqt5 and more, even try headless browser method for rendering also... but still no progress in any of those